Регулярные попытки клиента подключиться к серверу, регулярное ожидание клиентов сервером
Имеется программа клиент-сервер, нужно, чтобы при запуске .exe клиент самостоятельно осуществлял регулярные попытки снова подключиться к серверу, а сервер в свою очередь регулярно ожидал подключения. Как это можно реализовать на Си?
